# Multiplicities of components of a Springer fibre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-representation-theory, springer-fibres, symplectic-resolutions

Given a Springer fibre of type A, are multiplicities of its irreducible components known in general, or at least in the special cases of two-row/hook types?
By multiplicities I mean considering a Springer fibre $\mathcal{B}_e=\pi^{-1}(e)$ with a
scheme-theoretic structure coming from the Springer resolution  $\pi: \widetilde{\mathcal{S_e}} \rightarrow \mathcal{S_e}$ of the corresponding Slodowy variety $\mathcal{S_e}:=S_e \cap \mathcal{N}$ (intersection of Slodowy slice at $e$ and the nilpotent cone $\mathcal{N} \subset \mathfrak{sl}_n$).

Comment: Do you know of any example where the multiplicities are not 1?

Comment: Not in type A. In types D and E the sub-regular Springer fibres, given as trees of same Dynkin type, will have multiplicities according to the imaginary root of the corresponding affine system, thus will have higher multiplicity components.